# R+Hadoop: How to read CSV file from HDFS and execute mapreduce?

Tags: r, hadoop, rhadoop

In the following example:

```
  small.ints = to.dfs(1:1000)
  mapreduce(
    input = small.ints, 
    map = function(k, v) cbind(v, v^2))
```

The data input for mapreduce function is an object named small.ints which refered to blocks in HDFS.

Now I have a CSV file already stored in HDFS as

```
"hdfs://172.16.1.58:8020/tmp/test_short.csv"
```

How to get an object for it?

And as far as I know(which may be wrong), if I want data from CSV file as input for mapreduce, I have to first generate a table in R which contains all values in the CSV file. I do have method like:

```
data=from.dfs("hdfs://172.16.1.58:8020/tmp/test_short.csv",make.input.format(format="csv",sep=","))
mydata=data$val
```

It seems OK to use this method to get mydata, and then do object=to.dfs(mydata), but the problem is the test_short.csv file is huge, which is around TB size, and memory can't hold output of from.dfs!!

Actually, I'm wondering if I use "hdfs://172.16.1.58:8020/tmp/test_short.csv" as mapreduce input directly, and inside map function do the from.dfs() thing, am I able to get data blocks?

Please give me some advice, whatever!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

mapreduce(input = path, input.format = make.input.format(...), map ...)

from.dfs is for small data. In most cases you won't use from.dfs in the map function. The arguments hold a portion of the input data already

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice I can put the input format in mapreduce() argument! I read your wiki which said to.dfs and from.dfs are only used for small data and testing. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like below:

```
r.file <- hdfs.file(hdfsFilePath,"r")
from.dfs(
    mapreduce(
         input = as.matrix(hdfs.read.text.file(r.file)),
         input.format = "csv",
         map = ...
))
```

Please give points and hope anybody find it useful.

Note: For details refer to the stackoverflow post :

[How to input HDFS file into R mapreduce for processing and get the result into HDFS file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24953127/how-to-input-hdfs-file-into-r-mapreduce-for-processing-and-get-the-result-into-h/24956678#24956678)